# changing fieldName of Json twice

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-restcontroller

Is it possible to change Json field name two times in Spring rest api. I know it is not very meaningful but I need something like this.

For example the json which I am getting from the remote service is

```
{
    total_count : 1;
}
```

My Model  class is like

```
public class Model
{
     @JsonProperty("total_count")
     int count;
}
```

And from my rest service I want to return a json of Model class but with the field "count" instead of "total_count"

```
{
     count: 1
}
```

Is that possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public class Model {

  int count;

  @JsonGetter("count")
  public int getCount() {
    return count;
  }

  @JsonSetter("total_count")
  public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to disturb the pojo classes then you can follow below solution to format the json solution and send response.

On JSONObject do below.

```
obj.put("count", obj.get("total_count"));
obj.remove("total_count");
```